# (valid reason) Loading image outside Preload (p5js)

Tags: image, runtime, p5.js, preload

I want to know if there was a way to make sure an image was loaded when loading it outside Preload. I sometimes get “Uncaught ReferenceError: loadImage is not defined” and sometimes it loads. It doesnt seem to be predictable. The reason why I need to load outside preload is because I am creating a “preview art on your wall” module where clients load pictures of their wall at runtime in a product page via a “upload image” button in the page. They can change their wall as they please.

Answer (score 0):

You can call preload, by just doing preload(); anywhere. So I guess in your situation you'd just run preload(); when someone uploads a file, you can always add code in preload but try avoiding it.